# How to use Bootstrap Tags Input

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to use  **Markup** https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/ but couldn't get it work correctly

```css
.bootstrap-tagsinput {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  display: block;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  color: #555;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 4px;
  max-width: 100%;
  line-height: 22px;
  cursor: text;
}

.bootstrap-tagsinput input {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 0 6px;
  margin: 0;
  width: auto;
  max-width: inherit;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <input type="text" value="Amsterdam,Washington,Sydney,Beijing,Cairo" data-role="tagsinput">
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384- 
    KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

**Here is my output in the web browser**

[image]

Where i'm i mistaking and what are the missed imports

I'm using a template in my project .

Here is my desired output

[image]

Comment: You need to include javascript cdn bootstrap too.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I'm new to web development could you give me an example please

Comment: See the [SO wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bootstrap-4/info) for bootstrap-4

Comment: Another tips don't use this [plugin](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/) because it's used bootstrap 2/3

Comment: [bootstrap-tagsinput page](https://github.com/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput) states you need bootstrap-3.3.5, jquery-2.1.4 and typeahead-0.11.1, but TBH, it's a little low on details, so you might like to start with the bootstrap site on how to get that working first.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini agreed - I linked to SO wiki for bootstrap-4 as that was tagged, but yes, the plugin's page does have some outdated libraries.

Comment: thanks , @freedomn-m is there an updated plugin to use or a code sample  to test for input tags ?

Comment: I would decide which version of bootstrap you have/want and then search from there.

Comment: i'm using bootstrap 4.0.0

Comment: Whatever version you land on, use the latest minor/patch version. 4.0.0 is very old. See https://www.bootstrapcdn.com

Comment: Does migrating the version does not impact my web page . if not i will use any solution recommended . because i'm realy stack getting it work

Comment: @isherwood , do you have any idea how could i update my code to make it work ? thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, but your question lacks focus. Please see [ask]. You've been given lots of good advice here, so you need to _take it_ and regroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually include the libraries for bootstrap tagging. Have a look at the example page, they include it at the very end of the html markup.
[image]

Comment: thanks a lot that what i missed .